# Mercurial: Pushing a changeset to Repo A and somehow Repo B has it too?

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo on the server named "Gold" that exists as my production repo, a repo named "Silver" on the server that acts as a dev repo, and then obviously one or more repos on my local client. Strangely enough, when I push a changeset from my local dev machine to Gold, Silver also somehow gets the changeset. We are running Mercurial on Windows Server 2008R2 on IIS7.5.

Example:

**Server** (create Gold on server)

- mkdir Gold
- cd ./Gold
- hg init

**Client** (clone Gold to client)

- hg clone http://server/Gold Dev
- cd Dev
- echo "Foo" > bar.txt
- hg ci -Am "added file bar.txt"
- hg push

*At this point the client and server are in synch, each with one changeset.*

**Server** (clone Gold into Silver - a new dev repo - on server)

- cd ..
- hg clone ./Gold Silver

**Client** (commit & push change to Gold - not touching Silver)

- echo "Fizz" > buzz.txt
- hg ci -Am "added file buzz.txt"
- hg push

Now I would expect Gold to have two changesets and Silver to have one. In our environment here, **Gold & Silver both somehow have both changesets**! Any change we push to Gold automatically shows up in Silver. This seems incredibly unexpected to me - has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Does the new change set appear in the log, incoming or the working copy?

Comment: It shows up via hg log, but does not appear in the working directory (and nothing is incoming).

Comment: This looks like a bug (http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1922 seems a related issue). Maybe you can get help from the mercurial mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Rudi. Ry4n has provided a workaround below that I can use, but I'll also follow up on the mailing list - hopefully the root cause can be solved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm. That certainly shouldn't happen.  There are ways you could make it happen (using hooks), but it shouldn't happen on its own.

In the case of a local clone (your `hg clone ./Gold Silver` line) mercurial uses hardlinks under the covers to save on disk space, but it breaks those links on write.

As a test, however, you could change that line to:

```
hg clone --pull ./Gold Silver
```

which will use more diskspace, but be otherwise identical.

I don't expect that to fix anything, but I guess it's a good datapoint to have.

Comment: Your suggestion actually *does* work, which is great. I'd love to know why it is necessary though...