# mercurial repository corruption

Tags: mercurial

I’m new to mercurial, about 2 months now. We are using it on a new project and tried to create a new repo, a clone of the trunk, to be used as release “branch”.

We use a central repo, everyone is pulling/pushing to/from it over https using hgwebdir.cgi. Using on server hg 1.5.4 and “clients” various versions, 1.5.2 -> 1.6.3
Everything thing was ok. The clone was good (hg verify after clone), the only problem is that very soon this repo got corrupted (empty or missing ;   in manifests not found).

The main repo is ok, only this release get broken very soon.
The names of the repos are (folder names and published names, all reside in the same root folder):
A.B – for the trunk
A.B.Release – for the release repo
(read something in the docs, which sounded like this might be a issue – see

One other very strange thing is that checkins made only to trunk (A.B) are seen as available on the release branch, and they are displayed as errors on verify ( in manifests not found). Don’t understand how these got there.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then it could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453216/mercurial-pushing-a-changeset-to-repo-a-and-somehow-repo-b-has-it-too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer, but I'll state that what you're doing is definitely supposed to work.  Making sure the wire-protocol has full backwards compatibility is very important to the Mercurial folks.

The "cross-talk" between your two repos is very concerning and shouldn't happen unless someone erroniously used [the share extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension).

What if you try creating the A.B.Release clone by using `clone --pull` rather than clone by itself?

Comment: yes --pull solves the issue, as normal pull uses hardlinks to create the new repo and this is plain wrong from my point of view. Default should not do that, as one does not create a new repo just to have same data in two places they really want to independent repos.

Comment: Hardlinks are the way to go, softlinks can only be used to fool humans to think one file is really in another directory, because they get used to a directory layout. Internally, when using hardlinks, Linux knows that files are being copied and therefore keeps only one copy with a technique known as 'copy on write bit', which means that whenever one of the copies gets changes, the file is really copied. So you are obtaining no improvement by using softliks + you make hg get confused and files corrupted.